# Is there any way to change the key bindings for a controller?

Tags: legend-of-heroes-trails-in-the-sky

The fast forward button is defaulted to the right trigger button and I'm getting cramping in my finger from holding it in constantly. There is no option for key rebinding that I can see in any of the menus in the game. Is there some other way to change the defaults?